# May Api-platform work fine with Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm working on Symfony 3.4, and I wanna add Api platform.
After installing this last one(API), when I try to debug-routes, I'm not seeing my routes starting by api/
I don't know what's wrong.
Thanks to give me some suggestions

This is my composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "api-platform/api-pack": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^1.17",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "3.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "1.2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's already done in your project or not, but in order to have API Platform working you need to :

- Enable the bundle

```
// app/AppKernel.php
$bundles = [
    // ...

    new ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\ApiPlatformBundle(),
];
```

- Congifure Api Platform

```
# app/config/config.yml
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
```

- import API Platform routes

```
# app/config/routing.yml
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api
```

- Finally, use API Platform in your entity, like :

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Book.php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * ...
 *
 * @ApiResource
 */
class Book
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: All those steps are done, correctly...
But nothing is working

Comment: It's ok, i finally found were I was wrong

I was working with the original config of the installation of api-platform.

Answer (score 1):

Looking well the answer of #stephan.mada I remark that I was workin with the config of the package, Now I took

...
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
...

from

## config/package/api_platform.yaml

to

## App/config/config.yml

Same for the route

I moove

---

api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform

### prefix: /api

from

## config/routes/api_platform.yaml

to

## App/config/routing.yml

And now it's Of, thank to all for ur precious help